# load selected content from an acf select field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

On wordpress and ACF,
I am searching for a way to load different `<div>` (one OR the other, not both)
 based on 
the choosen content from the ACF « select » field (named « type_of_page »)
***when*** the page load.
I have two type of selector « actual » OR « archive »
that have to load two `<div>` « #now » OR « #before »

```
    <?php

if(get_field('type_of_page') == "archive")
{
    //...
}

?>

<div id="now">NOW</div>
<div id="before">BEFORE</div>
```

How sould I release that, without loading both ?

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much got it:

```
<?php if( get_field( 'key' ) == 'value' ) : ?>
  <div id="content-a"></div>
<?php else : ?>
  <div id="content-b"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you are worried that `content-b` will load but be hidden in cases where `content-a` is desired, check the source code after viewing the page in a browser. You will see that `content-b` cannot be loaded if `content-a` is loaded (and vice-versa) using this logic.